# Concatenatable numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Given a list of positive integers such as `[69, 420]`, your challenge is to generate the sequence of numbers that can be formed by concatenating numbers from the above set, in ascending numerical order.

For example, with `[69, 420]` the sequence begins:

```
69
420
6969
42069
69420
420420
```

Note that elements of the sequence should be unique.

The list will be nonempty and will not contain duplicates.

Standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) rules apply.

### Testcases

In `list, 0-indexed number` format.

```
[69, 420], 4 -> 69420
[32, 33, 34], 8 -> 3334
[109, 5], 7 -> 10955
[2, 22, 222], 4 -> 22222
```

Comment: I presume we don't have to handle the list being empty?

Comment: May we assume the list will contain no duplicates?

Comment: @pajonk Yes. (filler)

Comment: @pxeger No, you don't.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 71 bytes (-3 thanks to @pxeger)

```
def f(A):
 o=A
 while o:=o-{x:=min(o,key=int)}|{x+i for i in A}:yield x
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BCsIwEEX3PcWQVYIt6EKwgQpdiceodEKH1qSEVFNiTuKmG914Im9jtf7le_D-_dmPrjF6mh6DU9nufahRgeKlkAmYokzg2lCHYGRhsuBlcSbNTdriWJB2It6CXxEoY4GANJRRjoRdDf6fO_5U6r8S9XBGWznkiuOl6jjpfnBczJvPSAHtc3myWLUJ9HbOc8UCRQnBRyaW4PQKbLPOWcq2LC7oAw)

This takes a set of strings as its input.

#### Old [Python](https://www.python.org), 77 bytes

```
def f(A):
 o=A
 while o:O,*o=sorted({*o},key=int);yield O;o+=map(O.__add__,A)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYwxCsIwFED3niJ0-qlR2kHQlgw9gPQAIiGQRD_WJMRUqeJJXLro4om8jQX7xgfvPd--jwdnh-HVRTNffTdKG2KgpmVCHK8Tcj1gq4krG5Y5fnYhagX3zD3YUfccbaRVj7pVpKncjJ-kh2YhhFRKCFbTaVoYFwgStOSGHoK0ew1FTpkBfZEtoPVdBDpS-jAuAadw-GzTIl-nLF2mu7_6AQ)

A generator that walks through the sequence.

How does it work?

It maintains a list/set which always contains (or has yielded) all the concatenations of all numbers output so far with all numbers in the input list. At each iteration it yields the smallest element and adds its concatenations with the input list.

Comment: -3 bytes by using sets some more: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BDoIwEEX3nGLShSkREl2YSA0mLPUWGKZhArakKVpSexI3bHTjibyNKP7le8n792c32FqrcXz0Vqbb97FCCZIXsYhA58WiiOBaU4ughc516p3Iz6S4ThocclI2DjfvlgRSGyAgBUXYDYRtBe5fPPxU4r4SVX9GU1rkkuOlbDmprrc8njb9kQTaZ-JksGwi6MyU55J5CgK8Cyyeg-PLs_UqYwnbsDCjDw

Answer (score 8):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 60 bytes

Prints the sequence forever.

```javascript
a=>{for(k=0;;)(++k+'').match(`^(${a.join`|`})+$`)&&print(k)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCkAwFADQX/Egu7chSSLNj4h2U8sspll7wbfPOTsFulenL1@ELioRSYyPsg6MqIYBgXPDGcPyIL9uIBdIHyp3q0/5yg95KjHLLqdPDwa/qGBq@zxp6mrG@AM)

#### How?

We turn the list of integers into a regular expression:

```javascript
[69, 420] ~~> /^(69|420)+$/
```

And we use it to identify the positive integers that belong to the sequence.

Answer (score 7):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-F`, 30 bytes

```
seq inf|grep -xP (${(j"|")@})+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjWbSSrptS7IKlpSVpuhb7ilMLFTLz0mrSi1ILFHQrAhQ0VKo1spRqlDQdajW1IYqgaldGm1nqKJgYGcA0AwA)

Slow.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <sup><s>109</s> <s>108</s></sup> 104 bytes

```
a=input();i=0
m=lambda n:n*all(n.find(p)or m(n[len(p):])for p in a)
while 1:
 if""==m(`i`):print i
 i+=1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Lc1NCsIwEEDhfU4xZJX4R1tENJKTlEIjbchAMg0lRTyLm2zElQfyNgbq8n2b93zHR3ITNTm_lmT3568zGikuScgr6ooF7U24DQZI0cZ4L-hgkQYR5TRDENT6kUqoTtoCEZDASHZ36EeoFQO0nGsdRI-9VHFGSoBFt7pef_9t_rT8dOE74Mem4t2KPw)

-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 81 bytes

```
import re
def f(a,i=0):re.match(f'({"|".join(a)})+$',str(i))and print(i);f(a,i+1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwU31zNyC_KISheLKYi4g1itOLSlKTS4tKs7Mz8vJzM0s0TA0AALNpaUlaboWNwOhyotSuVJS0xTSNBJ1Mm0NNK2KUvVyE0uSMzTS1DWqlWqU9LLyM_M0EjVrNbVV1HWKS4o0MjU1E_NSFAqKMvNKgBxrsFZtQ6jBG9I0opXMLJV0FJRMjAyUYqHCCxZAaAA)

Dies with the recursion limit, but works theoretically (or if you use a Python interpreter with TCO)

Comment: `any((p<=n<p+'~')*m(n[len(p):])for p in a)` saves a byte.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
иæJïê¹£
```

Given \$n\$ and the list, it outputs the first \$n\$ results.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9vc2FiaWX//9C4w6ZKw6/DqsK5wqP//zEwCls2OSw0MjBd) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXCoZX/L@w4vMzr8PrDqw6tO7T4v87/6OhoM0sdEyODWB2TWB2F6GhjIx1jYx1jIMcMzDc0sNQxjdUxB3OMdIxAyAikOBYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
и        # Repeat the (implicit) second input-list the first (implicit)
         # input-integer amount of times as list
 æ       # Get the powerset of this list
  J      # Join each inner list together
   ï     # Cast each string to an integer
    ê    # Uniquify and sort the list
     ¹£  # Only leave the first first input amount of values
         # (after which this is output implicitly as result)
```

Too bad sorting builtins don't work on infinite lists, otherwise `ÞæJïê` would have been enough to output the infinite sequence given just an input-list.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
tT&j₎⊇ᵘcᵐoh↙T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9icmFjaHlsb2cy//90VCZq4oKO4oqH4bWYY@G1kG9o4oaZVP//W1s2OSw0MjBdLDVd/1o)

Extremely inefficient.

This returns the first N elements, 1-indexed.

#### Explanation

```
tT               Input = [List, T]
  &j₎            Concatenate List T times to itself
     ⊇ᵘ          Find all unique subsets of this new list
       cᵐ        Map concatenate
         o       Sort
          h↙T    Return the first T elements
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
xŒPḊVQṢḣ
```

A dyadic Link that accepts the list of positive integers on the left and the number of elements to get, `N`, on the right and yields a list of the first `N` concatenated integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//eMWSUOG4ilZR4bmi4bij////WzEsIDIzLCAxMDFd/zU)** - extremely inefficient!

#### How?

```
xŒPḊVQṢḣ - Link: list of positive integers, L; positive integer, N
x        - repeat the elements of L N times each
 ŒP      - powerset
   Ḋ     - dequeue (remove the empty list)
    V    - evaluate as Jelly code (concatenates each and gives back the integer)
     Q   - deduplicate
      Ṣ  - sort
       ḣ - head -> the first N elements
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
≔θζＦη«⊞υ⌊⁻ζυ≔⁺ζＩ⁺Ｉ⌈υＩθζ»Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU@jUEehStOaKy2/SEEjQ1OhmoszoLQ4Q6NUR8E3My8ztzRXA0iXFmtU6SiUamoCVXJCNQbkQESdE4tLIBwwyzexAqwLqBgqVwjUpgmxpZYroCgzrwSiEqjC@v//6GgzSx0FEyODWB0Fs9j/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` terms. Explanation: Based on @Albert.Lang's Python answer.

```
≔θζ
```

Start with the input list.

```
Ｆη«
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
⊞υ⌊⁻ζυ
```

Save the minimum value not collected so far.

```
≔⁺ζＩ⁺Ｉ⌈υＩθζ
```

Append all the concatenations of that value with the input list to the current list.

```
»Ｉυ
```

Output the collected terms.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ẋfṗvṅ⌊sUi
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuotm4bmXduG5heKMinNVaSIsIiIsIjRcblsyLCAyMiwgMjIyXSJd)

Port of the Jelly answer. Yields a list of the first N concatenated integers.

### Explained (outdated - will fix soon)

```
ẋfṗvṅ⌊sUi
ẋf        # Repeat the input list N times
  ṗ       # take the powerset of that list
   vṅ⌊    # Concatenate each sublist into a single integer
      sUi # and get the Nth item in the sorted uniquified list
```

Comment: [FYI 1-indexing](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuotm4bmXVXbhuYXijIpzaSIsIiIsIjRcbls2OSwgNDIwXSJd)

Comment: Doesn't handle `[2, 22]` correctly - [Fixed](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuotm4bmXduG5heKMinNVaSIsIiIsIjRcblsyLCAyMiwgMjIyXSJd)

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `lists.lazy`, <s>95</s> 82 bytes

```factor
[ 0 lfrom swap "|"join "^(%s)+$"sprintf <regexp> '[ present _ matches? ] lfilter ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1Na8JAFEX3/opLqFQRJC0iaKUuxY2b0lWwMgxv4tRxkrz3JE0/fnsaDbi8l3vuccZqwe3723a3WSJ4UZkG893gRBwpQKi6ULQkcAWfjaqPOZhy@irhuEHJJBS1J69JtSnZd01V42UwqOofzBeYPaf4azOkCI6LM6Q2JZLf5LPwEcnHaCjjyUMiN9Jh1Qte8ZjdBQd0dnskWWPfnfigxNi31oSAp7Q/DGpOhAzT64SMPbb/)

-13 bytes from using [@Arnauld's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248332/97916). Takes input as a sequence of strings representing integers and returns an infinite lazy list of the sequence.

Comment: [ATO has Factor v0.98](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?L=factor), which may be useful to you. (although `>dec` [still doesn't seem to work](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY89TsNAEIV7TvEuYAuDIiEipUU0NChVFKHxZpJYsdfLzFgCIS5BS-MmuVNuw8RbkGp-3vvm5_e0pWC9jOef5evzy9MjDiyRW3Rk-zL0Xd1Ecr0JiiSsHA3K7wPHwPqflfxhQjpRGU0kygLtxZq4u7Bmn0maa74UTkyTrmyK-c0XKtzdo7qt8I3ZcbBt8XB-W2GFbAW1baFDPdn9HMNFW2w4YO17UxH6GNzmjUXuoOOuZlH4G4OQ036RSwfmhD3TBuu85hR8NspcjGOOfw))

Comment: @pxeger Yeah I discovered it a couple weeks ago and it's been great for certain answers! But it's still 4 years old and `>dec` was [added to the language 3 months ago](https://github.com/factor/factor/commit/1945b8f54cd62c7d6dd811586ee21bf43d6794a6).

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 62 bytes

```
~(T`,`|
(\d+).(.+)
K`0¶$1{`.+¶$$.($*__¶/^($2)+$/^+`.+¶$$.($*__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/v04jJEEnoYZLIyZFW1NPQ09bk8s7weDQNhXD6gQ9bSCtoqehohUff2ibfpyGipGmtop@nDaKzP//pjpmljomRgYA) Takes `n` as the first input in the list and outputs the 1-indexed `n`th term. Explanation: Similar approach to @Arnauld's JavaScript answer.

```
T`,`|
```

Change the commas into `|`s.

```
(\d+).(.+)
```

Match the first number and the remaining numbers separately.

```
K`0¶$1{`.+¶$$.($*__¶/^($2)+$/^+`.+¶$$.($*__
```

Create a Retina program with them substituted in.

```
~(`
```

Evaluate that program.

For example, with the inputs `5,69,420` the following Retina program is created:

```
K`0
```

Set the current value to `0`.

```
5{`
```

Repeat `5` times.

```
.+
$.(*__
```

Increment the current value.

```
/^(69|420)+$/^+`
```

Repeat while the current value isn't a concatenation of `69`s and `420`s...

```
.+
$.(*__
```

... increment the current value.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 82 bytes

```r
function(n)repeat grepl(sprintf("^(%s)+$",paste(n,collapse="|")),F<-F+1)&&print(F)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctBCoAgEADAr4hU7KJBRQRBXX1GIKIRyCpqt/5u0WlOk6rbq7vJlCsQECYbrS7s/PSQY7qoOOAHtBlFw2XUuVggaYL3Oma784cjSrX1SozYdX8AhdWBgWWVbJ4GxPoC)

Port of [@Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248332/55372).

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
W1Ui~=+Xg&Pi
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLG51bGwsIkxtVWl+PStYZyZQaSIsIiIsIjIgMyIsIi1wIl0=) (link is to a safe version that only runs 1000 times)

-2 thanks to DLosc.

```
W1           # Forever
     ~=      # Check a regex match of...
        Xg   # Input regex'd
       +     # With a `+`
  Ui         # In (incrementing) i
         &Pi # If so, print i
```

Comment: (The code should be `W1Ui~=+Xg&Pi`)

Answer (score 2):

## BQN, 37 bytes

```
{⊑∧⍷•Bqn¨∾¨•Fmt¨¨1↓(⥊(↕2˘)/¨<)∾/⋈}
```

[Try it here!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAge/CdlajiipHiiKfijbco4oCiQnFu4oiY4oi+4oCiRm10wqgpwqgx4oaTKOKliijihpUyy5gpL8KoPCniiL7in5zwnZWp4o2f8J2VqPCdlal9CjQgRiA2OeKAvzQyMA==)

Slow enough that you'll probably need a local interpreter to run most of the cases.

2 bytes saved thanks to @Razetime!

## Explanation

*w* is index, *x* is list of numbers.

- `∾/⋈` *x* repeated *w* times
- `(⥊(↕2˘)/¨<)` powerset
- `1↓` remove empty set
- `•Bqn¨∾¨•Fmt¨¨` for each element in powerset, concatenate numbers

  - Super-slow since we're "eval"ing each string to get the number (BQN doesn't have an easy way to convert strings to numbers)
- `∧⍷` Deduplicate and sort
- `⊑` Get *w*th number

Comment: looks like this works: `{⊑∧⍷•Bqn¨∾¨•Fmt¨¨1↓(⥊(↕2˘)/¨<)∾/⋈}`

Comment: @Razetime thanks! I was stumped on finding a more elegant way to dupe the list, underestimated the power of `/`

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 16 bytes

```
Jx/jcb)imNB><j!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/Z@TV62ka6dkba0bW5D636tCPys5STMz18/JziZLUfF/bW70/2ozSwUTI4NaBRMFXTsFM0sgm6va2EjB2FjB2KRWwQIkamxsbMJVbWhgqWBaq2AOEgGyTU25qo0UjEDICKrbCAQA)

Takes block (L) and int (N)

```
J    # Duplicate N
x/j  # Make stack N,L,N
cb   # Combinations of L of length [1..N]
)im  # Concat each result
NB   # Remove duplicates
><   # Sort
j!!  # Select Nth
```